# expected number of steps for simple random walk by solving difference equation...limit problems...

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes

(below is the solved difference equation for a simple random walk to find the expected number of steps before the state k is absorbed in the 0 and N states: y(k) Now, I want to use this equation when p=q=1/2.)

If $p=q=1/2$ and $p+q=1$, then what is the value of:

$$y(k) = \frac{1}{q-p} \Bigg(k-N\bigg[ \frac{1-(q/p)^k}{1-(q/p)^N} \bigg] \Bigg)$$

Obviously, if you substitute the value of p and q into this equation you get indeterminate.

---

By analogy, the book solved a similar problem this way:

$$y(k) = \frac{\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^k - \left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^N }{1 - \left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^N}$$

let $r = \frac{p}{q}$

$$y(k) = \frac{r^k - r^N }{1 - r^N}$$

$$y(k) = \lim \limits_{r \to 1/2} \frac{r^k - r^N }{1 - r^N}$$

then applying L'hopital's rule you ge:

$$y(k) = 1 - \frac{k}{N}~~~~\text{when }p =q$$

---

What throws me off about the first problem above is the $\frac{1}{p-q}$ term... i'm not sure how to get rid of it by subsitituting the ratio $r=q/p$. so i can take the limit as $r \to 1/2$.

[image: answer]

Comment: Limit as $r\to1/2$? Don't you mean, limit as $r\to1$? Does it help to write $1/(p-q)=(1/p)/(1-(q/p))=2/(1-(q/p))$?

Comment: You are right $r \to 1$... it helps ... but how do you get $(1/p)/(1-(p/q))= 2/(1-(p/q))$?  Maybe it’s a double limit since it’s both r and p.. $\lim \limits_{r\to 1, p \to 0.5}$. That fixes the indeterminate problem...

Comment: When $p=1/2$, $1/p=2$.

Comment: Oh right! I forgot that you can just substitute the variable if it isn’t inderterminant.